Astro+ React application build Error: (1:0) Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error
I am trying to build the application by running the command
npm run build
but getting below errors
(1:0) Error when using sourcemap for reporting an error: Can't resolve original location of error.
(1:0) Module level directives cause errors when bundled, "use client" in "src/components/publicProfile/OrganisationPublicProfile.tsx" was ignored.
Trying to build the application with no error

Show us your OrganisationPublicProfile.tsx

Removing the use of "use client"; in these components should get rid of this warning/error. That directive isn't required in an Astro based project that uses React.

As @Alex had said in their comment, remove any 'use client' directives in the React files.
Astro does not need this directive
